# unique factorisation of non-zero fractional ideals in a Dedekind domain

Tags: proof-explanation, dedekind-domain

I'm reading about Dedekind domains from Serre's book, and on Pg. 12, before stating Proposition 7, there are arguments for the proof, which read as follows:

If one considers the ideal $a_1 = \displaystyle\prod_{p} p^{\nu_p(a)}$ and the ideal $a_2$ of those $x$ such that $\nu_p(x) \geq \nu_p(a)$ for all $p$, prime ideals in a Dedekind domain A, then the three ideals $a, a_1, a_2$ are equal locally (i.e, they have same images in all $A_p$). Here, $a$ is an arbitrary fractional ideal of $A$.

I don't understand how $a, a_1, a_2$ are equal locally. Please help me to understand.

Comment: Did you show that $A_p$ has a unique maximal ideal $p A_p = (\pi_p)$ for any $v_p(\pi_p)=1$ ? Then wlog assuming $v_p(a) \ge 0$ you have $a_p = a A_p \subset (\pi_p^{v_p(a)})$ so $\pi_p^{-v_p(a)} a_p \subset A_p$, by definition of $v_p$, $a_p \not \subset (\pi_p^{v_p(a)+1})$, thus $\pi_p^{-v_p(a)} a_p$ is contained in no power of $(\pi_p)$ thus in no maximal ideal thus it is the whole of $A_p$, as wanted $a_p = (\pi_p^{v_p(a)}) = p^{v_p(a)} A_p$. For $a_2$ show we can choose to take $\pi_p$ in $A$.

Comment: I think I got why $a$, and $a_1$ are equal locally. If someone could verify if it's correct, I would be very grateful to him: Since, A is a Dedekind domain, $(a_1)_q$ would be a discrete valuation ring, so it is of the form $(q^n)$ for some $n$, which means $\nu_q(a_1) = n$. But $\nu_q(a_1) = \displaystyle \sum_{p} \nu_p(a)\times\nu_q(p) = \nu_q(a)$. So, $a_q = (a_1)_q $

Comment: @reuns yes, I did show that $A_p$  has a unique maximal ideal. Nice work!. Can you check if my reasoning works?

Comment: and can you please explain a bit more for $a_2$?